# gdb error: Unable to execute epoll_wait: (4) Interrupted system call

Tags: c++, gdb

I am unable to run my code in debug using gdb because of the following error:

Unable to execute epoll_wait: (4) Interrupted system call

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should check the `epoll_wait` return value, then if it's `-1` compare `errno` to `EINTR` and, if so, retry the system call. This is usually done with `continue` in a loop.