# Is there any method to wait until task catch SIGALRM signal in intel arch?

Tags: c, linux, signals, eintr

I'm programming iwth gcc version 4.4.3 on Ubuntu 10.04
I don't know how to catch SIGALRM with sigtimedwait(),sigwait().

If timer handler is set , sigtimedwait(),sigwait() always returns EINTR(4).
If timer handler is not set, SIGALRM never received.

Is there any method to wait until task catch SIGALRM signal in intel arch?

```
void handler( int signo )
{
...
}

int main( void )
{
  timer_t timer_id;
  struct sigaction sigact;
  struct itimerspec itval;
  int ret;
  struct timespec pTimeout;
  siginfo_t pInfo;

  pTimeout.tv_sec = 10;
  pTimeout.tv_nsec = 0;

// set signal handler for SIGALRM
  sigact.sa_handler = handler;
  sigact.sa_flags = 0;
  sigemptyset( &sigact.sa_mask );

  sigaction( SIGALRM, &sigact, NULL );

// create timer
  timer_create( CLOCK_REALTIME, NULL, &timer_id );

  itval.it_value.tv_sec = 3;
  itval.it_value.tv_nsec = 0;

  itval.it_interval.tv_sec = 0;
  itval.it_interval.tv_nsec = 250 * 1000 * 1000;

// set timer
  timer_settime( timer_id, 0, &itval, NULL );

  int count;
  for ( count = 0; count < 10; count++ )
  {
// wait for SIGALRM

    ret = sigtimedwait
            (
                    &sigact.sa_mask,    /* the signal mask while suspended */
                    &pInfo,                    /* return value */
                    &pTimeout  
            );
 .....
   }
```

Comment: It's not clear why you're reusing `sigact.sa_mask` (which is empty) in the call to `sigtimedwait`. You're waiting for an empty set, so the alarm doesn't match. The comment `the signal mask while suspended` is completely out-of-place as far as I can tell.

Comment: As you said,I made a mistake.After revising first parameter of sigtimedwait,I came to get SIGALRM signal.Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Is this helpful?

```
do {
    ret = sigtimedwait(&sigact.sa_mask, &pInfo, &pTimeout);
} while (ret < 0 && errno == EINTR);
```

Similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6870158/epoll-wait-fails-due-to-eintr-how-to-remedy-this).

Comment: `sigtimedwait` does not return `EINTR`.

Answer (score 1):

Some of the 'wait until a signal is received' functions are:

- [`pause()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pause.html)
- [`sigsuspend()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sigsuspend.html)
- [`sigpause()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sigpause.html)

The `sigpause()` function is actually part of a deprecated set of functions; it is best not to use it in new code.

There is also:

- [`sigtimedwait()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sigtimedwait.html)

which may do what you want more directly.